# Parsing name and address from unstructured text

Tags: parsing, street-address

I am working on an application that requires me to parse unstructured
text. I need to parse name, address - area,city,country and zip code
from it. The addresses will be Indian.

Sample input:
"I am ABC working in XYZ company.
I am good at web designing having an experience of 3 years.
I live in kothrud,Pune-411038,Maharashtra."

Output:
NAME            : ABC
AREA            : KOTHRUD
CITY            : PUNE
STATE           : MAHARASHTRA
ZIP CODE        : 411038

I am planning to use Apache ConceptMapper for parsing cities and states
for which I will have to build a dictionary set myself, but I guess that
can be done. For the zip code, I can use regex. I am stuck at how to
parse a name and area. Regex can be used to get name and area with
little hacking and lots of patterns but I am wondering if there is any
better solution available.

Is there any database I can query to, that would return addresses? I
haven't looked into Google maps/places but can you achieve address
parsing with them easily?

Any inputs would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What context do you have to work with?  Meaning, are the addresses constrained to US addresses, or Indian addresses?  It will be very helpful to be able to limit to that.

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) can help with this. It will return the map coordinates for a given address or an appropriate status code if no match is found.